# Обрезать часть URL в начале

Tags: php, строки, url

Есть ссылка https://site.com/ru/moskov/baby/andyushak-evgeniya-petrovna

Нужно ее обрезать чтобы получить baby/andyushak-evgeniya-petrovnа..

Посоветовали вариант

```
substr(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1), strpos(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1), '/') + 1)
```

он работает, но убирает только https://site.com/ru/

а нужно и после второго слеша убирать

Answer (score 1):

Если сайт один и тот же и города не меняются (все время речь идет про Москву), то вот так:

```
$url = "https://site.com/ru/moskov/baby/andyushak-evgeniya-petrovna";
$url = str_replace("https://site.com/ru/moskov/", "", $url);
```

Этот код просто уберет из ваших ссылок `"https://site.com/ru/moskov/"` (соответственно вам нужно заменить на своё).

результат: `baby/andyushak-evgeniya-petrovna`

Если же города меняются и меняются языки, но структура остается такой же, то вот регулярное выражение, которое вырежет вам этот кусок. А именно уберет из ссылки сначала домен `http://site.ru/` (как `http`, так и `https`) и затем два "контейнера" между слешами. Первый - языковой (`/ru/`), второй - город (`/moskov/`).

Данные в них могут меняться, например язык на `/en/` а город на `/london/`.

```
(https?|http):\/\/\S*?\.\S*?\/\S*?\/\S*?\/
```

Я в регулярных выражениях на данный момент мягко говоря плаваю, и уверен что от идеала эта регулярное выражение сильно далеко, но с вашей задачей справится.

```
$url = "https://site.com/ru/moskov/baby/andyushak-evgeniya-petrovna";
$url = preg_replace('#(https?|http):\/\/\S*?\.\S*?\/\S*?\/\S*?\/#', "", $url);
```

результат: `baby/andyushak-evgeniya-petrovna`

Answer (score 1):

> *получить baby/andyushak-evgeniya-petrovnа*

Если структура URL не меняется, тогда можно обойтись и без регулярных выражений:

1. разбить URL на массив
2. взять необходимый срез массива
3. преобразовать результирующий массив в строку

---

```
$str = 'https://site.com/ru/moskov/baby/andyushak-evgeniya-petrovna';

$str = join('/', array_slice(explode('/', $str), 5));

echo $str;
```

---

[**Результат**](https://ideone.com/H4UcKa)